# jQuery find if div with id=X exists inside a DOM string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if a div with an id exists in a string holding some html, so I'm looking for a function that returns true or false.

There's a function hasClass that checks if a div has a certain class

```
$('#mydiv').hasClass('bar')
```

I guess what I'm looking for is something like

```
var mystring = "some string with html";

mystring.hasId('lookingforthisid');
```

How can I check this?

Comment: any reason for not using document.getElementById?

Answer (score 2):

Turn it to a jquery object and use the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to locate the element you want

```
var mystring = "some string with html";

var $mystring = $('<div>'  + mystring + '</div>');

alert( $mystring.find('#lookingforthisid').length );
```

if it has [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) greater than 0 then it exists..

---

**Improvement / Generalization**

If you want to make a general function to check if strings contain some jquery selector you can do this

```
String.prototype.hasSelector = function( aSelector ){
    return ($( '<div>' + this.toString() +'</div>').find( aSelector ).length>0) ? true : false;
};
```

and use it like this

```
var mystring = 'test <div id="someid">text in ID</div> outer <div class="someclass">text in class</div> ';

alert( mystring.hasSelector('#someid') );
alert( mystring.hasSelector('.someclass') );
```

Live example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/Ajp7K/

Answer (score 1):

> jquery find if div with id=X exists

Use the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
if($('#mydiv').length > 0){
  // element exists
}
else{
 // element does not exist
}
```

You can convert it to a function like this:

```
function element_exists(id){
    if($(id).length > 0){
      return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And use like:

```
if (element_exists('#some_id')){
  // element exists
}
else{
  // element doesn't exists
}
```

If you want to check if an element with certain class exists, you can use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method instead.

If you want to check if an element with certain piece of text exists, you can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) filter selector instead. Here is an example:

```
alert($('#element_id:contains("some text")').length);
```

Comment: Your element_exists function only checks within the document, not within an arbitrary string as he asked for. In fact if you want to look for an ID in the document you don't even need JQuery; Plain old Javascript/DOM has a perfectly good getElementById() function which would work just as well.

Comment: @Spudley: That last example checks for text too and the question is also tagged jquery.

Comment: @Sarfraz, the OP is asking to search in arbitrary text not in the DOM.

Comment: @Gaby: Well, we can't be sure because if you read question title, it clearly says find if an element exists with specified it. So let's what OP is up to :)

Comment: @Goby: I sure did, funny you said that. He said `I guess what I'm looking for is something like`. He himself is not sure. As I said let's wait for the OP.

Comment: @Sarfraz, not trying to be argumentative here.. You are correct that only the OP knows for sure.. :)

Answer (score 0):

find if element exists within a string of HTML:

```
if($("div#mydiv", mystring).length >= 1) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```