# This code cant find the div with a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you try this code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8BEpZ/

I'm trying to find a div with id "test" and if I don't find, I create it. The problem is that if I call this function many times, it re-creates the div all the time:

```
var divClasses = $('‪#test');
if (divClasses.length==0) {
    divClasses = $('<div />', { id:"test" }).appendTo('body');
    console.log('anormal !');
}
```

How comes?

Comment: I think he just create #test if it doesn't exist, and then, update it.

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153784/jquery-find-if-div-with-id-x-exists-inside-a-dom-string

Comment: What about remove `divClassess = bla bla bla` and put this one: `$('<div id="test"><div />');` inside your `if` statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your keyboard must be producing different characters than expected, either your `'` or `#` is incorrect. Can't figure out which one precisely since my Chrome dev tools keep crashing when playing with those characters..

You can see the difference between your '#test'

```
encodeURIComponent('#test')
-> "%E2%80%AA%23test"
```

and a `#test` typed in an english keyboard

```
encodeURIComponent('#test')
-> "%23test"
```

I think it's that opening quote, perhaps.

[image]

Comment: I copy it to console , but it's not like your result

Comment: The is an invisible unicode character called "LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING". Not sure about its purpose though.

Comment: That's some weird quote there - it acts as a normal quote, i.e. it works as a string opening character, etc. but that left-to-right embedding confuses Chrome console. When the cursor goes past that character.. it jumps to the beginning of the string.

Comment: How did this invisible character get embedded, is it some sort of RTL thing?

Comment: I also noticed this weird behavior of cursor.

Comment: @RoyiNamir it doesn't work if you paste from my answer, since the stackoverflow input 'sanitizes' that invisible character in some way. But if you paste the string from the original fiddle, you'll see that character in there.

Comment: @Karolis it is the same . 0D0A

Comment: Here is the info that might be relevant: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-controls.en.php?changelang=en

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` produces same result, in my chrome (without copy and paste)

Comment: `That's some weird quote there - it acts as a normal quote` <= +1! **It should not act as a normal quote** hence my question! Is that a bug or whatever? Anyway thank you very much for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

I checked out your jsfiddle. After changeing single quotes to double quotes it worked.

```
var divClasses = $('‪#test');
```

to

```
var divClasses = $("#test");
```

Comment: Yep thats right it does say in the jquery spec to use double quotes http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/ "Strings should always use double-quotes instead of single-quotes."

Comment: How could it impact on this? I know that we could have the problems when using strings, json obj. etc.. but here `$('#test')` ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with quotes. See Karolis answer.

Comment: Phew! So, my first comment is still valid :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8BEpZ/5/)

```
 if (!$('#test').length)  
 {    
   divClasses = $('<div />', { id:"test"}).appendTo('body');  
    console.log('anormal !');  
}
```

try removing that div and it should create a new one with same ID.

Answer (score -1):

You could just change the `.append()` to the `html()` method, which fits more on what you're trying to do : http://jsfiddle.net/8BEpZ/4/

*Et sinon, il faut vraiment arrêter de placer des styles directement avec JS, et encore moins des attributs de style HTML ;)*

Comment: How your code differs from the OP's? `var divClasses = $('‪#test');
if (divClasses.length==0) {`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var divClasses = $('‪#test');
if (divClasses == null) {
    divClasses = $('<div />', { id:"test" }).appendTo('body');
    console.log('anormal !');
}
```

Comment: Please add comments if you are down-voting any answer... It will help the user to provide better answers in the future.